# Connecting chat gui to socket client

Tags: python, sockets, pyqt5

I have a client-server chat program that I'm trying to connect to a GUI(pyqt5). I tried to move text from the GUI to the client using variables in "main" file that runs both client and GUI.

Basicly there's `to_server` in the GUI file(called "ichi.py"), that gets the text written in the line edit and in "main.py" I append the text to the messages list the client will send to the server. the client sends the message to the server and it spreads the message to all connected sockets. When the client receives a message it saves the text in `to_gui` which goes to the GUI's variable `from_server`. In the GUI there's a method that prints whatever there is in `from_server`.

The problem is that I can't keep the said variables up to date as the program continues.

The server:

```
import sys
import socket
import select
import datetime
# from urnd import Users_DB


class Server(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # self.users_db = Users_DB()
        self.server_socket = socket.socket()
        self.open_sockets = []
        self.sockets_names = {}
        self.admins = []
        self.muted_sockets = []
        self.public_msgs = []
        self.private_msgs = []
        self.rlist = []
        self.wlist = []
        self.xlist = []

    def open(self):
        self.server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 2303))
        self.server_socket.listen(5)

    def run(self):
        self.rlist, self.wlist, self.xlist = select.select([self.server_socket] + self.open_sockets, self.open_sockets, [])
        self.handle_new_connection()
        self.handle_receive_data()
        self.handle_sending_msgs()

    def close(self):
        del self.public_msgs[:]
        del self.private_msgs[:]
        self.public_msgs.append((None, "bye"))
        self.handle_sending_msgs()
        self.server_socket.close()

    @staticmethod
    def get_current_time():
        """Returns hh:mm"""
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        time = f'{now.hour}:{now.minute}'
        return time

    def get_name(self, user_socket):
        """Returns the name of the user_socket, if he is an admin he gets @ before his name"""
        name = self.sockets_names[user_socket]
        if len(self.admins) != 0:
            if user_socket in self.admins:
                name = "@" + name
        return name

    def get_data_length(self, data):
        """Returns the length of the data as string with length 3"""
        length = str(len(data))
        while len(length) < 3:
            length = "0" + length
        return length

    def get_socket_by_name(self, name):
        """Returns the socket with the name, if none exists return None"""
        if len(self.sockets_names) != 0:
            for socket_pair, socket_name in self.sockets_names.items():
                if name == socket_name:
                    return socket_pair
        return None

    def get_admins_as_string(self):
        admins_names_lst = []
        for admin_socket in self.admins:
            admins_names_lst.append(self.sockets_names[admin_socket])
        return str(admins_names_lst)[1:-1]

    def remove_socket(self, removed_socket):
        self.open_sockets.remove(removed_socket)
        if removed_socket in self.admins:
            self.admins.remove(removed_socket)
        del self.sockets_names[removed_socket]

    def handle_new_connection(self):
        for new_connection in self.rlist:
            if new_connection is self.server_socket:
                (new_socket, address) = self.server_socket.accept()
                self.open_sockets.append(new_socket)
                self.sockets_names[new_socket] = "Anonymous"
                if len(self.admins) == 0:
                    self.admins.append(new_socket)
                    print("New Connection And Admin")
                else:
                    print("New Connection")

    def handle_receive_data(self):
        for current_socket in self.rlist:
            if current_socket is not self.server_socket:
                data_length = int(current_socket.recv(3).decode('utf-8'))
                data = current_socket.recv(data_length).decode('utf-8')
                if data[0] == '/':
                    self.handle_commands(current_socket, data[1:])
                else:
                    self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "You: " + data))
                    if current_socket in self.muted_sockets:
                        self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, """"You are muted and so can't send msgs to everyone. 
                        You can ask one of the self.admins to unmute you in a private msg"""))
                    else:
                        self.public_msgs.append((current_socket, self.get_name(current_socket) + ": " + data))

    def handle_sending_msgs(self):
        for message in self.public_msgs:
            (sender_socket, data) = message
            data = self.get_current_time() + " " + data
            for receiver_socket in self.wlist:
                if receiver_socket is not sender_socket:
                    receiver_socket.send(bytes(self.get_data_length(data), 'utf8'))
                    receiver_socket.send(bytes(data, 'utf8'))
                    if message in self.public_msgs:
                        self.public_msgs.remove(message)

        for message in self.private_msgs:
            (receiver_socket, data) = message
            data = self.get_current_time() + " " + data
            if receiver_socket in self.wlist:
                receiver_socket.send(self.get_data_length(data).encode('utf-8'))
                receiver_socket.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
                if message in self.private_msgs:
                    self.private_msgs.remove(message)
                if data.split(' ')[1] == "bye":
                    self.remove_socket(receiver_socket)

    def handle_commands(self, current_socket, data):
        command = data.split(' ')[0].lower()
        data = ' '.join(data.split(' ')[1:])

        if command == "exit":
            self.public_msgs.append((current_socket, self.get_name(current_socket) + " left the chat."))
            self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "bye"))
            print("Connection with " + self.get_name(current_socket) + " closed.")

        elif command == 'rename' or command == 'setname':
            if data not in self.sockets_names.values():
                if data.lower() != "you" and data.lower() != "server" and data.lower()[0] != "@":
                    try:
                        # self.users_db.change_name(data, self.sockets_names[current_socket])
                        self.sockets_names[current_socket] = data
                        self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "Your name has been successfully changed to " + data + "."))
                    except MemoryError:
                        err = sys.exc_info()[0]
                        print(f"Error: {err}")

                else:
                    self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, data + " is not a valid name."))
            else:
                self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "This name is already taken."))

        elif command == 'setadmin' or command == "promote":
            if current_socket in self.admins:
                if data not in self.sockets_names.values():
                    self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "This name doesn't exist in this server."))

                else:
                    new_admin_socket = self.get_socket_by_name(data)
                    self.admins.append(new_admin_socket)
                    self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, data + " has been promoted to admin."))
                    self.public_msgs.append(
                        (current_socket, self.get_name(current_socket) + " promoted " + data + " to admin."))

            else:
                self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "You don't have access to this command."))

        elif command == 'kick' or command == 'remove':
            if current_socket in self.admins:
                if data not in self.sockets_names.values():
                    self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "This name doesn't exist in this server."))

                else:
                    kicked_socket = self.get_socket_by_name(data)
                    self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, data + " has been successfully kicked and removed."))
                    self.public_msgs.append((current_socket, self.get_name(current_socket) + " kicked and removed " + data))
                    self.private_msgs.append((kicked_socket, self.get_name(current_socket) + " kicked you."))
                    self.private_msgs.append((kicked_socket, "bye"))

        elif command == 'mute':
            if current_socket in self.admins:
                if data not in self.sockets_names.values():
                    self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "This name doesn't exist in this server."))

                else:
                    muted_socket = self.get_socket_by_name(data)
                    self.muted_sockets.append(muted_socket)
                    self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, data + " has been successfully muted."))
                    self.public_msgs.append((current_socket, self.get_name(current_socket) + " muted " + data))
                    self.private_msgs.append((muted_socket, self.get_name(current_socket) + " muted you."))

            else:
                self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "You are not an admin and so you have no such permissions."))

        elif command == 'unmute':
            if current_socket in self.admins:
                if data not in self.sockets_names.values():
                    self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "This name doesn't exist in this server."))

                else:
                    unmute_socket = self.get_socket_by_name(data)
                    if unmute_socket not in self.muted_sockets:
                        self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "This user isn't muted."))

                    else:
                        self.muted_sockets.remove(unmute_socket)
                        self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, data + " has been successfully unmuted."))
                        self.public_msgs.append((current_socket, self.get_name(current_socket) + " unmuted " + data))
                        self.private_msgs.append((unmute_socket, self.get_name(current_socket) + " unmuted you."))

            else:
                self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "You are not an admin and so you have no such permissions."))

        elif command == 'msg' or command == 'message' or command == "prvmsg" or command == "privatemessage":
            send_to_name = data.split(' ')[0]
            data = ' '.join(data.split(' ')[1:])
            if send_to_name not in self.sockets_names.values():
                self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "This name doesn't exist in this server."))

            else:
                send_to_socket = self.get_socket_by_name(send_to_name)
                self.private_msgs.append(
                    (current_socket, "You -> " + send_to_name + ": " + data))
                self.private_msgs.append(
                    (send_to_socket, self.get_name(current_socket) + " -> " + send_to_name + ": " + data))

        elif command == 'admin' or command == "admins" or command == "adminlist" or command == "adminslist":
            self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "self.admins: " + self.get_admins_as_string()))

        elif command == 'users' or command == "userslist" or command == 'user' or command == "userlist":
            self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "Users: " + str(self.sockets_names.values())[1:-1]))

        elif command == 'help' or command == '?':
            commands = """/rename <name> - change your name.\n/msg <user> <msg> - will send <msg> as a private massage that only <user>
                can see.\n/users - returns the names of all the connected users.\n/self.admins - returns  the names of all the connected self.admins.\n/exit - 
                will disconnect you.\n\nself.admins' Commends Only:\n/kick <user> - kick the <user> from the server.\n/promote <user> - will ser <user> to 
                be an admin.\nmute <user> - will no let him send public msgs, only privates.\nunmute <user> - will cancel the mute on this user."""
            self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, "\nCommands:\n" + commands + "\n"))

        # elif command == 'login':
        #     info = data.split()
        #     if len(info) is 2:
        #         # db_response = self.users_db.check_user_info(info[0], info[1])
        #         if db_response is "Connected Successfully!":
        #             pass  # close login gui
        #         elif db_response is "No such user exists!":
        #             pass  # unhide hidden label in login gui

        else:
            self.private_msgs.append((current_socket, command + " is not a valid command."))


server = Server()
try:
    server.open()
    while True:
        server.run()
finally:
    server.close()
```

The Client:

```
import socket
import select
import sys
from ichi import ui_mainwindow, QtWidgets


class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.__my_socket = socket.socket()
        self.close = False
        self.IP = ip
        self.PORT = port
        self.msgs = []
        self.to_gui = ''

    def send(self, msg):
        self.msgs.append(msg)

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.__my_socket.connect((self.IP, self.PORT))
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print("Connection error. Rerun program")

        while not self.close:
            rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([self.__my_socket], [self.__my_socket], [])

            if self.__my_socket in wlist:
                for msg in self.msgs:
                    # send to server the message
                    self.__my_socket.send(self.get_msg_length(msg).encode('utf-8'))
                    self.__my_socket.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))

            if self.__my_socket in rlist:
                data_length = int(self.__my_socket.recv(3))
                data = self.__my_socket.recv(data_length).decode('utf-8')
                if data.split(" ")[1] == "bye":
                    # self.input_from_server("\nDisconnecting, Bye!")
                    self.__my_socket.close()
                    self.close = True
                elif data == "Connected Successfully!":
                    # close login_gui
                    pass
                else:
                    self.to_gui = data

    @staticmethod
    def get_msg_length(message):
        """Returns the length of the msg as string with length 3"""
        length = str(len(message))
        while len(length) < 3:
            length = "0" + length
        return length


# client = Client("127.0.0.1", 2303)
# client.run()
```

The GUI:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'ichi.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class ui_mainwindow(object):
    def __init__(self, MainWindow):
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.messages_spot = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.cursor = QTextCursor(self.messages_spot.document())
        self.typingspot = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.Enter = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.to_server = 'open'
        self.from_server = 'open'

    def setup_ui(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.messages_spot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 60, 411, 261))
        self.messages_spot.setReadOnly(True)
        self.messages_spot.setObjectName("messages_spot")
        self.messages_spot.setTextCursor(self.cursor)
        self.typingspot.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 320, 371, 31))
        self.typingspot.setObjectName("typingspot")
        self.Enter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 320, 41, 31))
        self.Enter.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.Enter.setCheckable(False)
        self.Enter.setChecked(False)
        # self.Enter.hide()
        self.Enter.setObjectName("Enter")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.Enter.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_enter())
        self.typingspot.returnPressed.connect(self.Enter.click)

        self.print_from_server(self.from_server)

        self.retranslate_ui(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslate_ui(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Enter.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter"))

    def on_enter(self):
        text = self.typingspot.text()
        if text.isspace() is False and text != '' and text != 'open':
            self.to_server = text
            self.messages_spot.insertPlainText(f'•  You: {text}\r\n')
            self.messages_spot.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.messages_spot.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
            self.typingspot.clear()

    def print_from_server(self, text):
        if text.isspace() is False and text != '' and text != 'open':
            self.messages_spot.insertPlainText(f'•  {text}\r\n')
            self.messages_spot.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.messages_spot.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
```

The main:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from ichi import ui_mainwindow
import sys
from threading import Thread
from client import Client
from login import Ui_login_screen


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create client
    global client
    client = Client("127.0.0.1", 2303)

    t = Thread(target=client.run)
    t.start()

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = ui_mainwindow(MainWindow)
    ui.setup_ui(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()

    client.send(ui.to_server)
    ui.from_server = client.to_gui

    t.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several incorrect assumptions:

- The code placed after exec_() will only be executed when Qt finishes its work, in your case after the window is closed.
- Assuming that the foregoing was false, it should not work because `ui.from_server = client.to_gui` only assigns the value of the variable "to_gui" to "from_server", if it is changed after "to_gui" then "from_server" no will be notified.

I am not going to analyze the server code since I suppose the OP has tested it and it should work correctly. My solution proposes to use QTcpSocket to handle the data through signals and thus remove unnecessary complexity in this case of threads:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtNetwork


class Client(QtCore.QObject):
    messageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, ip, port, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._socket = QtNetwork.QTcpSocket(self)

        self.socket.readyRead.connect(self.onReadyRead)
        self.socket.connectToHost(ip, port)

    @property
    def socket(self):
        return self._socket

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onReadyRead(self):
        data_length = int(self.socket.read(3))
        data = self.socket.read(data_length).decode("utf-8")
        words = data.split(" ")
        if len(words) >= 2 and words[1] == "bye":
            self.socket.disconnectFromHost()
            self.close = True
        elif data == "Connected Successfully!":
            pass
        else:
            self.messageChanged.emit(data)

    def send(self, message):
        self.socket.write(Client.get_msg_length(message).encode("utf-8"))
        self.socket.write(message.encode("utf-8"))

    @staticmethod
    def get_msg_length(message):
        """Returns the length of the msg as string with length 3"""
        length = str(len(message))
        while len(length) < 3:
            length = "0" + length
        return length


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.client = Client("127.0.0.1", 2303)

        self.messages_spot = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
        self.typingspot = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.enter_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            self.tr("Enter"), inputMethodHints=QtCore.Qt.ImhNone
        )

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.messages_spot, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.typingspot, 1, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.enter_button, 1, 1)

        self.enter_button.clicked.connect(self.on_enter)
        self.typingspot.returnPressed.connect(self.enter_button.click)
        self.client.messageChanged.connect(self.print_from_server)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    def on_enter(self):
        text = self.typingspot.text()
        if text.isspace() is False and text != "" and text != "open":
            self.client.send(text)
            self.messages_spot.insertPlainText(f"•  You: {text}\r\n")
            self.messages_spot.verticalScrollBar().setValue(
                self.messages_spot.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
            )
            self.typingspot.clear()

    def print_from_server(self, text):
        if text.isspace() is False and text != "" and text != "open":
            self.messages_spot.insertPlainText(f"•  {text}\r\n")
            self.messages_spot.verticalScrollBar().setValue(
                self.messages_spot.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi @eyllansec, I found a good solution. I created attributes in Client and ui_mainwindow classes that initiate with none- as "handlers". In main.py I connect between the handlers to send msgs and print them!